# How to get all files from firebase storage?

Tags: android, firebase

I have uploaded some files into Firebase directory and I want to list them and download one by one.There is no API/Documentation fo this.Could you help me ?

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files

Comment: What about if you have 10 files and you do not know the name and the format of all the files ?

Answer (score 5):

As of July 2019, [version 18.1.0](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#version_1810) of the Cloud Storage SDK now supports listing all objects from a bucket. You simply need to call `listAll()` in a `StorageReference`:

```
StorageReference storageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();


// Now we get the references of these images
storageRef.listAll().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<ListResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(ListResult result) {
        for(StorageReference fileRef : result.getItems()) {
            // TODO: Download the file using its reference (fileRef)
        }
    }
}).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(Exception exception) {
        // Handle any errors
    }
});
```

If you want to download these files, you can use one of the [options shown in the Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files#download_files).

Please **note** that in order to use this method, you must opt-in to [version 2 of Security Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/rules-behavior#security_rules_version_2), which can be done by making `rules_version = '2';` the first line of your security rules:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
```

Answer (score 2):

first , you should get the file download Url to retrieve it, the easiest way is to upload a file and generate the download Url in your database, so after that you just go and retrieve each file from the storage like this :

```
 private void downloadFile() {
    FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
    StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReferenceFromUrl("<your_bucket>");
    StorageReference  islandRef = storageRef.child("file.txt");

    File rootPath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "file_name");
    if(!rootPath.exists()) {
        rootPath.mkdirs();
    }

    final File localFile = new File(rootPath,"imageName.txt");

    islandRef.getFile(localFile).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
            Log.e("firebase ",";local tem file created  created " +localFile.toString());
            //  updateDb(timestamp,localFile.toString(),position);
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
            Log.e("firebase ",";local tem file not created  created " +exception.toString());
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I personally use this method, whenever you upload a file, save its download URL in your Firebase Database, if you are uploading multiple files then save it in an array. There is no method for Firebase Storage android to download and upload multiple files in one go.
Whenever you want to download files access your firebase database for those URL's.